# It is possible to exclude many of IP address on multiple lines?

Tags: configuration

[image]

It is possible to exclude many of IP address on multiple lines?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as per the [manual entry for ExludeExitNodes](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#ExcludeExitNodes):

```
   ExcludeExitNodes node,node,...
       A list of identity fingerprints, country codes, and address
       patterns of nodes to never use when picking an exit node---that is,
       a node that delivers traffic for you outside the Tor network. Note
       that any node listed in ExcludeNodes is automatically considered to
       be part of this list too. See the ExcludeNodes option for more
       information on how to specify nodes. See also the caveats on the
       "ExitNodes" option below.
```

However, it is not recommended and it is also not recommended to change the `MaxCircuitDirtiness` and `HiddenServiceStatistics` applies only to relays, not to clients. Your config looks ill-conceived and harmful.